# subselect pandas dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to remove certain specific repeating rows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nrows = 144    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrows,), pd.date_range('2016-02-08 00:00:00', periods=nrows, freq='2h'), columns=['A'])
```

The dataframe is continuous with time, providing data every two hours ad infinitum, but I've chosen to only show a subset for brevity.I want to remove the data every 72 hours at 8:00 starting on Mondays to coincide with an external event that alters the data.For this snapshot of data I want to remove the rows indexed at 2016-02-08 08:00, 2016-02-11 08:00, +3D etc..

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to remove. 36 hours != 3 days and 2016-02-08 is not a monday.

Comment: In the US, February 8th, 2016 IS a Monday.

Comment: Yeah, I must have been looking at the wrong calendar. So you want to remove 2016-02-08 08:00 (the first monday), 2016-02-11 08:00 (3 days after) and 2016-02-14 08:00 (6 days after) and also 2016-02-15 08:00 (monday) and then restart the count from here?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could do this:

```
In [18]:    
start = df.index[(df.index.dayofweek == 0) & (df.index.hour == 8)][0]
start

Out[18]:
Timestamp('2016-02-08 08:00:00')

In [45]:
df.loc[df.index.difference(pd.date_range(start, end=df.index[-1], freq='3D'))]

Out[45]:
                            A
2016-02-08 00:00:00  0.323742
2016-02-08 02:00:00  0.962252
2016-02-08 04:00:00  0.706537
2016-02-08 06:00:00  0.561446
2016-02-08 10:00:00  0.225042
2016-02-08 12:00:00  0.746258
2016-02-08 14:00:00  0.167950
2016-02-08 16:00:00  0.199958
2016-02-08 18:00:00  0.808286
2016-02-08 20:00:00  0.288797
2016-02-08 22:00:00  0.508109
2016-02-09 00:00:00  0.980772
2016-02-09 02:00:00  0.995731
2016-02-09 04:00:00  0.742751
2016-02-09 06:00:00  0.392247
2016-02-09 08:00:00  0.460511
2016-02-09 10:00:00  0.083660
2016-02-09 12:00:00  0.273620
2016-02-09 14:00:00  0.791506
2016-02-09 16:00:00  0.440630
2016-02-09 18:00:00  0.326418
2016-02-09 20:00:00  0.790780
2016-02-09 22:00:00  0.521131
2016-02-10 00:00:00  0.219315
2016-02-10 02:00:00  0.016625
2016-02-10 04:00:00  0.958566
2016-02-10 06:00:00  0.405643
2016-02-10 08:00:00  0.958025
2016-02-10 10:00:00  0.786663
2016-02-10 12:00:00  0.589064
...                       ...
2016-02-17 12:00:00  0.360848
2016-02-17 14:00:00  0.757499
2016-02-17 16:00:00  0.391574
2016-02-17 18:00:00  0.062812
2016-02-17 20:00:00  0.308282
2016-02-17 22:00:00  0.251520
2016-02-18 00:00:00  0.832871
2016-02-18 02:00:00  0.387108
2016-02-18 04:00:00  0.070969
2016-02-18 06:00:00  0.298831
2016-02-18 08:00:00  0.878526
2016-02-18 10:00:00  0.979233
2016-02-18 12:00:00  0.386620
2016-02-18 14:00:00  0.420962
2016-02-18 16:00:00  0.238879
2016-02-18 18:00:00  0.124069
2016-02-18 20:00:00  0.985828
2016-02-18 22:00:00  0.585278
2016-02-19 00:00:00  0.409226
2016-02-19 02:00:00  0.093945
2016-02-19 04:00:00  0.389450
2016-02-19 06:00:00  0.378091
2016-02-19 08:00:00  0.874232
2016-02-19 10:00:00  0.527629
2016-02-19 12:00:00  0.490236
2016-02-19 14:00:00  0.509008
2016-02-19 16:00:00  0.097061
2016-02-19 18:00:00  0.111626
2016-02-19 20:00:00  0.877099
2016-02-19 22:00:00  0.796201

[140 rows x 1 columns]
```

So this determines the start range by comparing the [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek) and [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour) and taking the first index value, we then generate an index using [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and call [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html#pandas.Index.difference) on the index to remove these rows and pass these to `loc`

Comment: This solution is close to the desired output and would work if only I wanted to mask data on Mondays.However, I need to mask data every 3 days(72 hours), starting on Monday.

Comment: Your original post was for 36 hours, you can just change the `freq='3D'` and it should work